# Not able to execute Akka Work pulling java example provided in the akka document

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-cluster, akka-persistence

I am interested in understanding the [work pull feature](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.7.0/typed/reliable-delivery.html#work-pulling) in akka. I am trying to create a main method for the [example provided](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.7.0/akka-cluster-sharding-typed/src/test/java/jdocs/delivery/WorkPullingDocExample.java) that will create and start the producer(ImageWorkManager class in the example) and consumer(ImageConverter class in the example). It will be helpful if someone provides a sample main method for executing the sample example.

Comment: "Please provide a guide" isn't a good form for a StackOverflow question. Please rephrase to a specific question. Such as a specific error you are having trying to run the example in the docs.

Comment: @DavidOgren, I had updated my question. Basically, I am looking for a main method that creates and triggers the producer and consumer in Akka Work pulling example (https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.7.0/akka-cluster-sharding-typed/src/test/java/jdocs/delivery/WorkPullingDocExample.java).

Comment: If you click on "source" in the snippets, it links you to the complete example in GitHub which includes a main method. https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.7.0/akka-cluster-sharding-typed/src/test/java/jdocs/delivery/PointToPointDocExample.java#L8-L17

Comment: hi @DavidOgren but the source you shared is for point-to-point pattern in which the main method is present. I am checking the work pull pattern which does not includes a main method. https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.7.0/akka-cluster-sharding-typed/src/test/java/jdocs/delivery/WorkPullingDocExample.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had figured it out. Below is the main class to create a producer actor in the given [work pull example](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.7.0/akka-cluster-sharding-typed/src/test/java/jdocs/delivery/WorkPullingDocExample.java).

```
public class WorkPullCreateProducer {
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    final ActorSystem<Command> system = ActorSystem.create(ImageWorkManager.create(), "ClusterSystem");
    final ActorRef<Command> ref = system;   
    Convert img = new Convert("gif", "jpeg", "imagename");
    ref.tell(img);
}}
```

and below is the main class to create a consumer actor.

```
public class WorkPullCreateConsumer {
public static Behavior<Void> create() {
    return Behaviors.setup(context -> {
        int workersPerNode = context.getSystem().settings().config().getInt("transformation.workers-per-node");
        for (int i = 0; i < workersPerNode; i++) {
            context.spawn(ImageConverter.create(), "Workernode" + i);
        }
        return Behaviors.empty();
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActorSystem.create(AppWorkPullConsumerStack.create(), "ClusterSystem");
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete sample under [Akka Samples](https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/tree/main/akka-sample-distributed-workers-scala). As I said in the comments, I think you are going to have to be more specific with any issues you are having if you are running into problems.